# How to add a div class to Wordpress Auto Nav?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code to display all pages into a nav bar in Wordpress

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
</ul>
```

Trying to figure out how to add a div class to each li?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use link_before and link_after:

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&link_before=<div class="myClass">&link_after=</div>'); ?>
</ul>
```

There's a section on styling the `<li>`s in [the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages).